# Boolean in xsd generated Java code

Tags: xsd, boolean, wrapper, primitive-types

I'm creating a java class based on an xsd file, and since one of the elements is a boolean with a minOccurs of 0, it generates a Boolean variable once translated in Java. This starts a chain of problems and, before digging my head in it, I'd like to know if it's possible to avoid having that from the root, having a regular boolean instead of the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove minOccurs it will generate Primitive boolean and default value will be false.

Hope this helps

Comment: minOccurs was unfortunately needed. It was a compiler bug, solved in subsequent versions